# Слово "ровно" может выступать в значении "точно"?

Tags: синонимы

> Пресловутая каннская лестница находится **ровно** напротив ещё одного
>   отеля, построенного тем же Франсуа Андре, отеля, который считается
>   одним из лучших и, безусловно, одним из самых знаменитых в мире.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может.

[**Словарь русских синонимов**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/dic_synonims/154653/%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE) (и другие словари):
**ровно**
**точно**, совершенно, прямо, аккурат, в точности, чисто...

Словарь синонимов русского языка. Практический справочник:
**ровно**
1. гладко
2. прямо; как по ниточке (или по линейке) (разг.)
3. см. спокойно 1
4. **точно**, точь-в-точь, в точности; ровным счётом, ни больше ни меньше, как в аптеке, как раз (разг.); аккурат, чик-в-чик, тик-в-тик, тютелька в тютельку (прост.)
/ о деньгах, копейка в копейку (разг.)
5. см. **точно**.
6. см. как бы

*Если стоять спиной к морю, то она* [беседка ветров] *находится **ровно напротив** Вас на вершине скалы Шаган-Кая* (в переводе с татарского “Соколиная гора”).

*Участок находится **ровно напротив** Юсуповского дворца, который и является конечной точкой нашей прогулки.*

Answer (score 1):

По-моему, нужно добавить тире перед вторым словом "отеля".

§ 175. Тире ставится в качестве дополнительного знака после запятой перед словом, которое повторяется для того, чтобы связать с ним новое предложение (чаще придаточное, усиливающее, дополняющее или развивающее главное предложение) или дальнейшую часть того же предложения, например:

*Я знала очень хорошо, что это был муж мой, не какой-нибудь новый, неизвестный человек, а хороший человек, – муж мой, которого я знала, как самоё себя.*
Л. Толстой

*Теперь же, судебным следователем, Иван Ильич чувствовал, что все без исключения, самые важные, самодовольные люди, – все у него в руках.*
Л. Толстой

[**Грамота**](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/rules/158-tire)

Comment: Я позволила себе отредактировать Ваш ответ. **Надеюсь**, моя правка его не испортила. P.S. Я отвечала, собственно, **только** на вопрос и не рассматривала особенности пунктуации. Отдаю должное Вашей *замечательности*.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова, Cпасибо за правку. Ваши правки всегда "по делу"! (Совсем не обязательно информировать меня о них в комментариях).